# How to enable/open developer/console window in Edge for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, microsoft-edge

I am using iPad iOS version 12.1

How do I enable developer/console window using the Edge browser?

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, MS Edge for the iPad provides a limited functionality. Users can use MS Edge for browsing, but developer tools are not provided with this version of MS Edge.

If you think that this feature should be available in MS Edge for the iPad then you can try to provide your feedback to user voice.

Here is the Microsoft [User Voice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer) link for this request.